# How to get the span values of checked box and display in textbox in jquery?

Tags: jquery, addition

Hi all iam working on jquery here i have a value in span tag i need to get that value and need    to display in textbox once it is checked and if i checked multiples boxex i need to get  add those values and  and have to show in textbox

here my code follows:

```
        <input type="checkbox"  />
        <span>100</span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>200</span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>300</span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>400</span>
         <input type="text" />
```

could any body help to make this work thanks in advance

Comment: i ahd tried with check box values but i have to display value in span so i din't getany idea to get the value of apan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `next` method you can select the next siblings of the checkboxes.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      var val = 0;
      $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
          val += parseInt( $(this).next().text(), 10 )    
      })  

     $('input[type=text]').val(val)
})
```

Comment: thanks for my reply it's working small help can u explain me                      val += parseInt( $(this).next().text(), 10 ) how this flow goes here              @undefined

Comment: @Shakil You are welcome, of course, this code iterates through checked checkboxes and selects the next sibling of the them that are span elements, then using `parseInt` converts the string to number and sets the result as value of the input.

Comment: yeh i got it but about parseInt( $(this).next().text(), 10 ) u had given the value of 10 whats the use of 10 thanks for reply  @udefined

Comment: @Shakil That's the `radix`, without specifying that you will get unexpected results. You can find more information on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all the checked values with this code.

If you change the HTML to this:

```
<button id="go">Test</button>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox"  />
    <span>100</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>200</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>300</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>400</span>

</div>
<input id="results" type="text">​
```

Then, you can use this to collect the text from all the checked boxes.  You could do it without changing the HTML, but this is much cleaner and safer from maintenance changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#go").click(function() {
        var data = $("input:checked").map(function() {
            return $(this).closest(".container").find("span").text();
        }).get().join(", ");
        $("#results").val(data);
    });
});​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jLEDC/